# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Trying to solve this problem,

```
  class Person
      def initialize(name)
        @name=name
      end

      def greet(other_name)
       puts "Hi #{other_name}, my name is #{name}"
      end
    end

    initialize("ak")
    greet("aks")
```

but I am getting the error like:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments calling `initialize` (1 for 0)
```

I don't understand what is asking here, if its just the argument then why the error is like (1 for 0). can someone help me understand this problem.

Comment: Notice that you also need to change `#{name}` to  `#{@name}` in order to reference the instance variable set in the initialize method.

Comment: Notice that `#@name` is enough, you don't need `#{@name}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize( name )
    puts "Initializing Person instance #{object_id}"
    @name = name
  end

  def greet( name )
    puts "Hi #{name}, I'm #{name()}"
  end
end
```

When you wrote `initialize` without explicit receiver:

```
initialize( "ak" )
```

It was only a matter of luck that your message was recognized. Look who has responded:

```
method( :initialize ).owner
#=> BasicObject
```

`BasicObject`, the foremother of all `Object` instances, herself responded to your call, by scolding you about wrong number of arguments, because:

```
method( :initialize ).arity
#=> 0
```

Not only this method does not expect any arguments, but also you are not expected to call it at all. In fact, you are not expected to call `#initialize` on any object by yourself, save for exceptional situations. `Class#new` method handles calling of `Person#initialize` method for you:

```
A = Person.new( 'Abhinay' )
Initializing Person instance -605867998 
#=> #<Person:0xb7c66044 @name="Abhinay">
```

`Person.new` handled creation of a new instance and automatically called its `#initialize` method. Also, `#initialize` method is created private, even if you did not specify it explitcitly. The technical term for such irregular behavior is [*magic*](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2010/07/13/ruby-initialize-and-super.aspx). `Person#initialize` is magically private:

```
A.initialize( 'Fred' )
NoMethodError: private method `initialize' called for #<Person:0xb7c66044 @name="Abhinay">
```

You cannot just reinitialize yourself to 'Fred', you know. All other methods are public unless prescribed otherwise:

```
A.greet "Arup"
Hi Arup, I'm Abhinay
#=> nil
```

Comment: But don't complain about it being too radical =)

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I wouldn't ever... :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to call the methods on the object (not just call the methods) and initialize is automatically called when creating a new object:

```
p = Person.new("ak")
p.greet("aks")          #=> "Hi aks, my name is ak"
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that to create new object you need to call method `new` on class, and not `initialize` on the object.

So code looks like this:

```
p = Person.new("John")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look at code below:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(other_name)
    puts "Hi #{other_name}, my name is #{name}"
  end
end

person = Person.new("ak")
person.greet("aks")

#=> Hi aks, my name is ak
```